# I am building a laundry room in the basement. Do I need a drain?

Tags: plumbing, drain

I am finishing a basement with a laundry room in it.

Do I need a drain over there?

The floor for the laundry will be tile.

Comment: If you don't want a swimming pool you need a drain lots of pools do have tile.

Comment: Just curious, if you DIDN'T have a drain...where would you expect all of the water from the washing machine to go?

Comment: Sure you need a drain. But you might be asking if you need a floor drain?

Answer (score 1):

You will need a standpipe for the washer to drain into, and a floor drain.  You will also want to make sure the finished floor slopes slightly towards the drain.

The standpipe should be obvious - if you don't have that the washer will just shoot water out the back when it drains.  Make sure it is vented properly.

You need the floor drain for when the washer leaks.  Washers can leak for a lot of reasons and they can dump a lot of water quickly - you don't want that water finding its way under the flooring, into the walls, and into any adjacent rooms.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely need a standpipe with a trap. Plumbing code requires 2" pipe for this.

The floor drain would be optional. There is no requirement for it in the plumbing code. It would however be convenient for overflow problems and cleanup.

I recently talked to a workmate at the box store though, and he was having to make a lot of repairs because his dishwasher overflowed and wrecked some of the kitchen sub-flooring. So, again a floor drain would be convenient in several areas of the house but is not required.

Good luck!